# The value of my recaptcha token is being saved in Chrome as an Address 1 field

Tags: html, forms, recaptcha

I have a form on my website on which I'm using ReCaptcha. The form collects address information, and for some reason, Chrome offers to save the address, but puts the ReCaptcha token as the value for Address 1.

I have a field on the form named customer_shipping_address1 that I would expect to be what Chrome picks up as the Address 1 field to save.

Does anyone have insight as to what may be going on here?

**Edit**: minimal code sample that reproduces problem on my server:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ReCaptcha weirdness</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" id="CustomerForm" method="post">
<div>
    <h1>Shipping Address</h1>
</div>

<label for="customer_shipping_address1">Address</label>
<input type="text" id="customer_shipping_address1" name="customer_shipping_address1" placeholder="Your address.." required>

<label for="customer_shipping_city">City</label>
<input type="text" id="customer_shipping_city" name="customer_shipping_city" placeholder="Your city.." required>

<label for="customer_shipping_state">State</label>
<select name="customer_shipping_state" id="customer_shipping_state" required>
            <option value="none" >Select State</option>
            <option value="ME" >Maine</option>
            <option value="MD" >Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA" >Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI" >Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN" >Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS" >Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO" >Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT" >Montana</option>
    </select>

<label for="customer_shipping_zipcode">Zipcode</label>
<input type="text" id="customer_shipping_zipcode" name="customer_shipping_zipcode" placeholder="Your zipcode.." required>

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[MY SITE KEY]"></div> 

<input type="submit" name="submitAction" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note** While removing all the extra css and script from the code for this sample, I found that if I remove the div tags around the h1 "Shipping Address", then the problem goes away. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Can you upload the code from your form?